# Is there a way to operate a K-Nearest-Neighbot classification in Matlab using a table with element that have different dimensions?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn

I'm trying to make a program in Matlab that classifies some experimental observations of a phenomenon based on 6 parameters: "time" and "observation" are two 1x18000 vectors, then there are 3 scalar parameters and a boolean parameter. 
One scalar parameter and the boolean parameter define the class for the classification of the observations and the other 2 are simple scalar parameters that give informations on the experimental observation.

 Now, I've created a Matlab Table using a for loop iterating to read all of the workspaces containing the observed data and used the `struct2table` function to generate it. 
a generic element of the table has the form `[1x18461 double]    [1x18461 double]       double        double      double      true`

Now, I wanted to create a model for the K-Nearest Neighbor algorithm using the Matlab function `Model =fitcknn(ds_test_data, 'double_property');`

but I keep getting the error messages:

```
Error using classreg.learning.internal.table2FitMatrix>makeXMatrix (line 180)
Table variable time must be a column vector.

Error in classreg.learning.internal.table2FitMatrix (line 113)
[Xout,vrange,CategoricalPredictors] = makeXMatrix(X,PredictorNames,CategoricalPredictors,OrdinalIsCategorical);

Error in classreg.learning.classif.FullClassificationModel.prepareData (line 485)
            [X,Y,vrange,wastable,varargin] = classreg.learning.internal.table2FitMatrix(X,Y,varargin{:});

Error in ClassificationKNN.prepareData (line 878)
                prepareData@classreg.learning.classif.FullClassificationModel(X,Y,varargin{:},'OrdinalIsCategorical',true);

Error in classreg.learning.FitTemplate/fit (line 217)
                    this.PrepareData(X,Y,this.BaseFitObjectArgs{:});

Error in ClassificationKNN.fit (line 863)
            this = fit(temp,X,Y);

Error in fitcknn (line 261)
    this = ClassificationKNN.fit(X,Y,RemainingArgs{:});

Error in Prova_K_Nearest_Neighbor (line 56)
Model =fitcknn(ds_test_data, 'double_property');
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I wouldn't use KNNs for this. They are very primitive algorithms. Try to find other relationships between the data that don't require them.                                                    Maybe Gaussian mixture models (take your time to find what is most suitable for this) ... Take a look at this website: https://blogs.oracle.com/datascience/when-k-means-clustering-fails%3a-alternatives-for-segmenting-noisy-data

Comment: kNN takes a matrix as input (and thus all variables to be of the same type), so convert everything to a matrix. You should scale your data to the [0,1] as this best represents true/false and the scaling massively affects any distance measure